# Spring IntegrationFlow CompositeFileListFilter Not Working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have two filters regexFilter and lastModified.

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
            .localDirectory(this.getlocalDirectory(config.getId()))
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .regexFilter(config.getRegexFilter())
            .filter(new LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter())
            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundDirectory())
            , e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(60_000)
                    .errorChannel(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL).errorHandler((ex) -> {

    })))
```

By googling I understand I have to use CompositeFileListFilter for regex so change my code to

```
.filter(new CompositeFileListFilter().addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(config.getRegexFilter())))
```

Its compiled but on run time throws error and channel stooped and same error goes for

```
.filter(ftpPersistantFilter(config.getRegexFilter()))
.
.
.

public CompositeFileListFilter ftpPersistantFilter(String regexFilter) {
        CompositeFileListFilter filters = new CompositeFileListFilter();
            filters.addFilter(new FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter(regexFilter));
        return filters;
    }
```

I just want to filter on the basis of file name. There are 2 flows for same remote folder and both are polling with same cron but should pick their relevant file.

**EDIT**
adding last LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter. Its working fine but adding upon request.

```
public class LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter implements FileListFilter<LsEntry> {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter.class);
private static final long DEFAULT_AGE = 60;

private volatile long age = DEFAULT_AGE;

private volatile Map<String, Long> sizeMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();


public long getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public void setAge(long age) {
    setAge(age, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public void setAge(long age, TimeUnit unit) {
    this.age = unit.toSeconds(age);
}

@Override
public List<LsEntry> filterFiles(LsEntry[] files) {

    List<LsEntry> list = new ArrayList<LsEntry>();

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

    for (LsEntry file : files) {

        if (file.getAttrs()
                .isDir()) {
            continue;
        }
        String fileName = file.getFilename();
        Long currentSize = file.getAttrs().getSize();
        Long oldSize = sizeMap.get(fileName);

        if(oldSize == null || currentSize.longValue() != oldSize.longValue() ) {
            // putting size in map, will verify in next iteration of scheduler
            sizeMap.put(fileName, currentSize);
            log.info("[{}] old size [{}]  increased to [{}]...", file.getFilename(), oldSize, currentSize);
            continue;
        }

        int lastModifiedTime = file.getAttrs()
            .getMTime();

        if (lastModifiedTime + this.age <= now ) {
            list.add(file);
            sizeMap.remove(fileName);
        } else {
            log.info("File [{}] is still being uploaded...", file.getFilename());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

PS : When I am testing filter for regex I have removed LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter just for simplicity. So my final Flow is

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
            .localDirectory(this.getlocalDirectory(config.getId()))
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .filter(new CompositeFileListFilter().addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(config.getRegexFilter())))
            //.filter(new LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter())
            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundDirectory()),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(60_000)
                    .errorChannel(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL).errorHandler((ex) -> {
                try {

                    this.destroy(String.valueOf(config.getId()));


    configurationService.removeConfigurationChannelById(config.getId());

//                // logging here
                } catch (Exception ex1) {
            }
            }))).publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
            .subscribe(f -> {

                f.handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)
                        .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                        .remoteDirectory(config.getOutboundDirectory()), c -> c.advice(startup.deleteFileAdvice()));

            })
            .subscribe(f -> {
                if (doArchive) {
                    f.handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
                            .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundArchiveDirectory()));
                } else {
                    f.handle(m -> {
                    });
                }

            })
            .subscribe(f -> f
            .handle(m -> {

                // I am handling exception here
            })
            ))
            .get();
```

and here are exceptions

```
2020-01-27 21:36:55,731 INFO o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 

'application.2.subFlow#0.channel#0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-01-27 21:36:55,731 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - stopped 2.subFlow#2.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2020-01-27 21:36:55,731 INFO o.s.i.c.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.2.subFlow#2.channel#0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-01-27 21:36:55,731 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - stopped 2.subFlow#2.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
```

**EDIT**
After passing regex to LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter and handle there works for me. When I use any other RegexFilter inside CompositeFileListFilter it thorws error.

```
.filter(new CompositeFileListFilter().addFilter(new LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter(config.getRegexFilter())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show, please, your final flow. I don't see that you use `LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter` in your `CompositeFileListFilter`... You definitely can't use `regexFilter()` and `filter()` together - the last one wins. To avoid confusion we suggest to use a `filter()` and compose all those with `CompositeFileListFilter` or `ChainFileListFilter`.

Also what is an error you are mentioning, please.

Comment: I have updated question. LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter is working fine already.

Comment: Does it work now? Can you just remove this SO thread then? I'm not sure what we can discuss since you don't provide clear question. And doesn't look like an exception...

Comment: No its not working for me. I agree is not an exception but channels are getting closed without transferring files.

Comment: Can you, please, then modify your question for most specific info. Right now it is not clear what really is your flow and what error you have. BTW, when you test polling flows like this, you have to be sure that block somehow in the test method because the flow is executed in the other scheduling thread. So, you may exit from your test method much earlier, than messages reach your channels. For testing, though, you also can consider to use `MockIntegration`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

Comment: .filter(new CompositeFileListFilter().addFilter(new LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter(config.getRegexFilter()))) I pass my regex inside LastModified and handle there.

Comment: its perfect sir